# NFS client under WSL - mount.nfs: No such device

Tags: nfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting the following error trying to mount a nfs export.

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.175:/mnt/nas /mnt/c/nas
mount.nfs: No such device
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This might be useful, you can actually mount NFS in Windows 10 natively https://mapr.com/docs/51/DevelopmentGuide/c-mounting-nfs-on-a-windows-client.html

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2020: You can mount nfs with wsl2, but wsl2 itself requires a hardware virtualization available. See here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5838

Answer (score 2):

If like me you are stuck on WSL1 you can work around this issue by mapping the drive in windows. Use the **Map Network Drive** feature and create a drive letter for your nfs mount e.g. G:

Now in WSL you can mount that drive letter:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/g
sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g
```

from: [How to Mount Windows Network Drives in WSL](https://www.public-health.uiowa.edu/it/support/kb48568/)

I have not tested the access speed to a drive mapped through to WSL like this but I would expect it to be slow!

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates the nfs kernel modules are not loaded correctly and
also verify the exported path "/mnt/nas" exists on sever "192.168.1.175" or not.

Comment: The exports on the server are fine. I can mount them on the same machine or other Linux boxes. This is just on Windows under WSL. Any idea what a kernel module means running under WSL?

Comment: Not sure the WSL is supporting NFS or not.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/

Answer (score -1):

first of all,we understand nfs is one of tctp/ip protocol, so one client and one server are needed, So our purpose is sharing a dir on windows or wsl to a another linux, that means the windows or wsl is a server, all you guys are right about wsl nfs, it doesnt work if we use the wsl nfs inside, we can make a another nfs server on windows instead of wsl, and configure the share dirs right which we can find the dirs on wsl, e.g. `/mnt/d/WORK/tftpserverDir`, after that we can mount successfully. those are tips of me:

1. make a nfs server on windows
   I dowwnload from this:

   https://www.hanewin.net/nfs-e.htm
2. configure the shared dir in exports file

   D:\WORK\tftpserverDir -name:nfsroot -umask:000 -public -mapall:0
3. mount the share dirs on your dst linux

mount -t nfs -o nolock -o tcp -o rsize=32768,wsize=32768 172.10.10.80:/nfsroot  /sdcard/mnt