# nfs mount in ubuntu throws: mount.nfs: No such device

Tags: nfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My `/etc/fstab` looks like this

```
10.xx.xx.xx:/usr/local/myfolder /usr/local/myfolfer nfs rw,soft 0 2
```

Then on running `sudo mount -a` command it throws `mount.nfs: No such device` error. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. I am able to mount it on other Ubuntu devices but it keeps failing on wsl.

Comment: Might be same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952569/nfs-client-under-wsl-mount-nfs-no-such-device
It's possible that WSL doesn't support it